MySQL GRANT command with environment variables in Docker Compose
I have a Docker Compose setup for a MySQL service, where I'm trying to use environment variables to configure the MySQL user during initialization. Here's a snippet of my Docker Compose configuration:
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    env_file:
      - ./env/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    logging: &logger
      driver: syslog
      options:
        tag: "{{.DaemonName}}(image={{.ImageName}};name={{.Name}};id={{.ID}})"

In my env/mysql file, I have a field called MYSQL_USER and in my SQL initialization script (init/01.sql), there's a line like this:
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%';
However, this command encounters an error: ERROR 1410 (42000) at line 5: You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT.
Interestingly, when I use the actual value instead of the environment variable, like
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';
it works perfectly. It seems like the issue might be related to how the environment variable MYSQL_USER is being expanded in my SQL script. When I use ${MYSQL_USER}@%, the variable ${MYSQL_USER} is not being expanded to its value, and instead, it's being treated literally as ${MYSQL_USER}. I suspect this might be causing the problem.
Is there any way I can use an environment variable in my SQL script so that it's properly expanded to its value during execution?

related to (or, the easiest way to do this): How can I use an environment variable in the MySQL

or, if you like scripting: envsubst

Thanks @Luuk but the provided solution demonstrates how to use environment variables in constructing the MySQL query string within a shell script, however my problem is within the MySQL query itself.

I think you need to convert this "MySQL query string" before you use it as "MySQL query", because the MySQL client is not capable of handling environment variables.
